# Harmonic harmonic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the form of functions $Y:R \to R$ such that the function in $(x,z) \to Y(x/z)$ is harmonic .

Can I find this form of function ? 
I need find function Y such that Laplace $Y = 0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x,z)=Y(x/z)$. First of all $Y$ should be a $C^2-$ function.

Now compute $u_{xx}$ and $u_{zz}$.

$u$ is harmonic $ \iff u_{xx}+u_{zz}=0$.

It is your turn to show that this is equivalent to $Y''=0$.

Comment: uxx = (1/z^2)Y''(x/z) and uzz=x^2 Y''(x/z).       So , uxx+uzz=o if x=1/z  , so Y(x/z)=Y(x/(1/x)) = Y(x^2 ) . This is correct ??

Comment: Sorry ,, if x=-1/z , so Y of the form Y(-x^2 ) . This is correct ??